should I be concerned about financial assistance I asked at work
I asked for financial assistance from my employer. Now he is checking my loan history with the company. Should I be concerned?

Do you have a reason to be concerned? Have you gotten previous loans from the company? If so, did you pay them back on time?

It sounds like a perfectly reasonable action. We don't know you, we don't know him, we don't know who your business or what company you work for - - how the heck could we answer this better than you can?

Is "loan history with the company" referring to whether the company has provided financial aid to you in the past? Why do you think this should be concerning when you ask your employer give you financial aid, that they then engage with the system revolving providing financial aid to employees?

Is there anything to be concerned about? This seems similar to a different question I was recently reading about an individual who took a loan from a customer or was going to before their nonpayment load history with the company was shared with the customer

I don’t understand the situation. Your employer is the company, aren’t they? So they are just checking their own books. This seems perfectly reasonable. Why do you think you should be concerned?


Should I be concerned?

Depends. Its somewhat unusual to take loans from your employer (unless it's a bank). So it depends on why you have taken loans and what shape they are in.
Unless there is a good reason to approach your employer it's better to get loans through a "traditional" channel, banks, credit unions, etc.

I'd say "usually better". Some companies, especially small ones, are willing to occasionally advance some money to be deducted from future paychecks.

Though I would say that if you aren't on starvation wages and the need isn't urgent you should be concerned about your money management, and whether there is any way you could be saving more so you don't need to resort to this in the future.
